# Why unstyled table is displayed for a second before footable styling is applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, footable

I am displaying a table with 100 rows retrieved from web service call. Then i am calling `$(".footable").footable();` But on every page, the unstyled table is flickering before the styling is getting applied.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found a solution for this issue, after many days research.

`display:none` was not working because it hides an element, and it will not take up any space. The element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as if the element is not there.

But the problem was resolved by giving `visibility: hidden;`

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can hide table using CSS property 'display:none' until page gets loaded.

Comment: Once we make it hidden, the footable styling is not getting applied.

Comment: Footable pagination and sorting is getting implemented. But columns are not hidden in tablet and mobile devices.

Comment: On document ready event, hide table by display:none.
Then make table display:block before you call  $(".footable").footable();